# how to set focus to specific textbox in current gridview row after postback from textchange event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Got a series of textboxes in a GridView that have postback enabled.  When I type some text in one of the txtQuantity and move to a txtUnit textbox, it triggers an OnTextChanged event and does a postback  to calculate some totals.   But the focus is lost on the txtUnit control and I have to re-select it with the mouse.  It's a bit annoying having to do this, is there a way to retain focus on these controls during a postback

---

**ASPX Page:**

```
<asp:gridview ID="grdOrder" CssClass="table table-hover" GridLines="None" 
            runat="server" ShowFooter="true" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"  ClientIDMode="Static"
        onrowdatabound="grdOrder_RowDataBound" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridheader">

       <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product">

            <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Label ID="lblProductId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("INVENTORY_ITEM") %>' Visible = "false" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" 
                    ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control input-sm"
                     AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">

            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QUANTITY")%>'  class="form-control input-sm" Style=" text-align:right;"
                     ClientIDMode="Static" onkeypress = "return IsDecimal(this);" ontextchanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

            </ItemTemplate>
]
        </asp:TemplateField>

        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit">

            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnit" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%#Eval("UNIT_NAME")%>' 
                 ontextchanged="txtUnit_TextChanged" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

</asp:gridview>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void txtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)sender;
    GridViewRow gridViewRow = (GridViewRow)txtQuantity.NamingContainer;
    DropDownList ddlProduct = (DropDownList)gridViewRow.FindControl("ddlProduct");
    Label lblGrossQuantity = (Label)gridViewRow.FindControl("lblGrossQuantity");
    TextBox txtUnit = (TextBox)gridViewRow.FindControl("txtUnit");

    //gridViewRow.Cells[3].FindControl("txtUnit").Focus();
    txtUnit.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried 'myControl.Focus();' at the end of your handler?

Comment: yeah i did it in txtQuantity_TextChanged event

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `PostBack` happens **after** your `_TextChanged` EventHandler. Therefore you need to capture something there, and pass it to `PreRender`. Use a `Session` variable to control the focus on `PostBack` and access it in `Page_PreRender()`.

```
protected void txtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)sender;
     GridViewRow gridViewRow = (GridViewRow)txtQuantity.NamingContainer;
     DropDownList ddlProduct = (DropDownList)gridViewRow.FindControl("ddlProduct");
     Label lblGrossQuantity = (Label)gridViewRow.FindControl("lblGrossQuantity");
     TextBox txtUnit = (TextBox)gridViewRow.FindControl("txtUnit");

     //gridViewRow.Cells[3].FindControl("txtUnit").Focus();
     Session["event_control"] = ((TextBox)gridViewRow.FindControl("txtUnit"));
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Session["event_control"] != null)
        { 
            TextBox control = (TextBox) Session["event_control"];
            control.Focus(); 
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException inEx)
    {
    }        
}
```

Or, you can use **javascript** instead of **Page_PreRender**

```
<body onload='setFocusToTextBox()'>

<script> 
    function setFocusToTextBox(){ 
         document.getElementById('<%= Session["event_control"] %>').focus();
    } 
</script>
```

The reason you're seeing a delay before the focus gets set is because that textbox is your default focus. If you don't want that delay, you can create a hidden textbox with the default focus that nobody sees, they'll just see the correct textbox get the focus.

Comment: SetFocus can only be called before and during PreRender exception at control.focus()

Comment: When I change quantity in second row, focus is getting set to txtUnitName in first row after postback from txtQuantity

Comment: If you view the source, are the textbox id's between rows unique? Try changing it to `ClientIDMode` to `AutoID` instead of `Static`

Comment: Its working fine. but initially focus moves to 1st row and comes back to second row instantly

Comment: And? Did you try adding a hidden textbox with the default focus in order to not see the delay? I've given 3 different ways to satisfy your request, now it's just implementing the best option to avoid some unwanted behavior thats not part of the original question.

Comment: its a dynamic grid. I cannot use hidden textbox

Comment: You can put a hidden textbox anywhere on the page, not just in your Grid.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
protected void txtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your working code
    GridViewRow myRow = ((Control)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
    myRow.FindControl("txtUnit").Focus();
}
```

Comment: This is the code that happens after the text changes. The PostBack occurs after that, therefore making this solution moot.

Comment: try with just one .Parent instead of .Parent.Parent, I forgot to mention that this depend on your targeted framework version

Comment: The problem is only setting the focus. For example when I am trying to change in txtQuantity in second row in grid, Focus is setting to txtUnitName in First row after postback

Answer (score 0):

You can give **`TabIndex="0"`** to the first textbox in gridview you want to focus first and **`TabIndex="1"`** on which you want to move the cursor automatically after postback

Change

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QUANTITY")%>'  class="form-control input-sm" Style=" text-align:right;"
                     ClientIDMode="Static" onkeypress = "return IsDecimal(this);" ontextchanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

via

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QUANTITY")%>'  class="form-control input-sm" Style=" text-align:right;"
                     ClientIDMode="Static" onkeypress = "return IsDecimal(this);" ontextchanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" TabIndex="0"></asp:TextBox>
```

AND

Change

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUnit" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%#Eval("UNIT_NAME")%>' 
                 ontextchanged="txtUnit_TextChanged" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Via

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUnit" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%#Eval("UNIT_NAME")%>' 
                 ontextchanged="txtUnit_TextChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: I didn't get any difference after adding the tab index.When I change quantity in second row, focus is getting set to txtUnitName in first row after postback from txtQuantity